Error "c.g is not a function" grpc-web , how to fix?
I write in JS and use GRPC.
When sending to server the Wp category , I get the error "c.g is not a function".
I tried to regenerate just a file, rechecked it many times, and I sent the correct data types. I did not send an array with categories, but categories individually. Whenever I add add category to the code, I get an error.
  const handleCreateResource = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputErrors = validateInputs();

    const metadata = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accesskey}`,
    };


    if (Object.keys(inputErrors).length === 0) {
      try {
        
        const request = new CreateResourceRequest();
        
        request.setName(resourceName);
        request.setDescription(resourceDescription);
        request.setLanguage(resourceLanguage);
        request.setUri(resourceUri);
        request.setLogin(resourceLogin);
        request.setPassword(resourcePassword);
        request.setPrice(resourcePrice);
        request.setWalletid(handleCreateId());
        
        
                // request.addCategories(response.categories);
                const categories = [];
                const keys = Object.keys(checkboxes);
                keys.forEach((Key, index) => {
                  if (checkboxes[Key] && Key !== "all") {
                    categories.push(selectedCategories[index]);
                  }
                });
                //console.log("категории", categories);
                

                request.addCategories(categories);
                
                console.log(request);
                
                
        const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          clientResource.createResource(request, metadata, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              resolve(response);
            }
          });
        });

        const responseObject = response && typeof response.toObject === "function" ? response.toObject() : response;
      console.log("Resource creation successful: ", responseObject);

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Resource creation failed: ${err.message}`);
      }
    } else {
      setErrors(inputErrors);
    }
  };

message CreateResourceRequest {
  // наименование ресурса
  string name = 1;
  // описание
  optional string description = 2;
  // язык
  Language language = 3;
  // ссылка
  string uri = 4;
  // логин
  string login = 5;
  // пароль
  string password = 6;
  // decimal цена, разделитель запятая 
  string price = 7;
  // id кошелька
  string walletId = 8;
  // wp категории
  repeated category_service.WpCategory categories = 9;
}


Your question is not a minimal repro making it difficult for others to help. gRPC-Web is sufficiently complex to repro that (a) I understand why you didn't publish a repro :-); (b) I can't be bothered to create a repro either. IIUC the issue only arises when you try to submit a request that includes request.addCategories(categories). I've a sneaking suspicion that addCategories is to add a single ``new Category()and so you'd need to create the Category and then useset{Field}methods on it beforeaddCategories. Alternatively there should be a setCategoriesList([categories])` method
